# Rails 3 Confirm Delete - Title not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following Michael Hartl's tutorial. Using Rails 3.0.9 under Ubuntu. The following line is in application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

No jQuery.  Tutorial [Listing 10.38](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3adelete_links) specifies the Delete action be called as follows:

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?",
                            :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

The generated HTML includes the title tag, e.g.:

```
<a href="/users/13" data-confirm="You sure?" data-method="delete" 
 rel="nofollow" title="Delete Mylene Gaylord">delete</a>
```

I assume the purpose of specifying a title is for the popup to identify which user will be deleted.  However the title is never displayed in the confirmation popup.  Instead:

- Firefox 3 under Ubuntu:  Title shows as "The page at http://0.0.0.0 says:".
- Firefox 5 under Win7:  No title at all; popup appears "Ajaxified" with browser dimmed in background
- IE8 under Win7:  Title shows as "Message from webpage".

Can Rails display the title in the popup?

Can I write an RSpec test to confirm that the title is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title option that's used there is specifically for the link title so that when you hover your mouse over the link, the value of title shows up as a sort-of tooltip.

If you want to add things like a title to your popup messages, you'll need to roll your own popups that support that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I see those tooltips now. Too bad they don't copy to the popups automatically!